React - Frontend Component submit handler calling API function doing a fetch, but not waiting for the returned value
I have a handler for a form submit that takes a user image, sends it to the back, does stuff on that image, and gives the modified image back (as a base64) to the front to be displayed.
Sending and receiving the image from the back works fine. But after receiving the image in the front API, I cannot give it to front Component, because the component handler is not waiting for the front API return.
Component that has the form and handler :
function Workshop() {

  // Used to store and update the front when data are modified
  const [imageUpload, setImageUpload] = useState(); 
  const [imageGenerated, setImageGenerated] = useState();

  // Handle the submit of the form
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Append the user image to the formData object
    setImageUpload(event.target.files[0]);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", imageUpload);

    // Calls the FrontEnd API with the image to be modified
    if(imageUpload) {
      const res = frontAPI.callGenerateImage(formData);
      console.log("back to front"); // ### THIS IS WHERE IT DOESNT WORK ###
      console.log(res); // ### THIS IS WHERE IT DOESNT WORK ###
      setImageGenerated(res); // ### THIS IS WHERE IT DOESNT WORK ###
    }
  };

  return (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    <>
      <div className="workshop">
        <form method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="imageUploader" onChange={handleImagePreview} />
            <img alt="preview image" src={imagePreview} />
            <button type="submit">Modify Image</button>
        </form>
        <img alt="generated image" src={"data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageGenerated} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Workshop;

FrontEnd API with the fetch :
export function callGenerateImage(formData) {
  var  base64;
  fetch("/generator", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
  })
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(res => {
    base64 = Buffer.from(res.data, "binary" ).toString("base64");
    console.log(base64); // THIS IS THE BASE64 STRING IN THE OUPUT BELOW
    return base64;
  })
};

Output :

So as you can see, I do receive the base64 stream of my modified image, but the line const res = fontAPI.callGenerateImage(formData); doesn't wait for the actual return of the fetch and goes on with the console.log("back to front"); .
I tried to switch my API function to an async function and change
const res = frontAPI.callGenerateImage(formData);

to
const res = await frontAPI.callGenerateImage(formData);

But it doesn't work because I'm not at top level, even if I remove the "if", as I am in a function of the component.
I'm fairly sure that the answer is pretty simple but I don't see it.
Thanks a lot for your help !
EDIT : PROBLEM SOLVED, SEE MY ANSWER BELOW

In your function callGenerateImage(formData) you don't return fetch(...) itself, but just call it.

I tried to return the fetch but all it does is replacing the "undefined" with a promise object that is still not waiting, so my base64 isn't in it.

You already have got the solution for it with const res = await frontAPI.callGenerateImage(formData);, it does the trick

I tried it, but frontAPI.callGenerateImage(formData); is in a handler function of the functional component, which means I'm not at top level and I get an error for that when trying to use "await".

Oh, yes, sorry! You can use const handleSubmit = async (event) => { with it (as one of the options).

I got it to work thanks to jbcortez89 and lo-fi wi-fi.
I needed to fix 2 things in my code :
A) Switching the handler to an async function, which I didn't even know was possible this way, which somehow allows me to use await even if I'm not at top level :
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault()
if (imageUpload) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", imageUpload);

    const res = await frontAPI.callGenerateImage(formData);
    setImageGenerated(res);
}

B) Fix my API fetch return value. I decided to switch to the new format which is much clearer than the nested then().
export async function callGenerateImage(formData) {
  let myData = await fetch("/generator", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
  })
  
  let dataJSON = await myData.json();
  return Buffer.from(dataJSON.data, "binary" ).toString("base64"); 
};

thanks a lot guys for your help !

Use async/await in your submit function and you'll be able to get the result.
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const file = event.target.files[0];

    if (file) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);

        const res = await frontAPI.callGenerateImage(formData);
        setImageGenerated(res);
    }
}

Also, you shouldn't set state and then check the state value within the same function. When you run setImageUpload() and then check if (imageUpload), you're not going to get the updated state until the next time you call the submit function. Instead, set it to a variable like I did.

Hi ! thanks for you reply. Ok I'm getting somewhere. Thanks to your reply and
lo-fi wi-fi's, I now have a handler waiting for "callGenerateImage". However, the console.log(res) in the Component returns "undefined". I guess I'm misusing the fetch now, not returning the value properly.

I tried doing what you did with the const file = event.target.files[0];, but for some obscure reasons, I get an error that it is not defined. I'm not sure why, as it SHOULD be. I tried removing the "onChange={handleImagePreview}" on the input itself, to see if it was overriding something somehow, but even without it, I get a "event.target.files is undefined".
